# Auto Calculated value doesn't appear as valid number until it is not edited in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to post an invoice form with autocalculated total value that depend on quantity and unit price, but onSubmit, the backend can't see the numeric amount of value and vatValue, except when I'm adding something on that autocalculated input. I can't resolve this even if I mark value and vatValue as dirty and touched. Any ideea can be helpful, thanks!

```
<input formControlName="name" placeholder="prod name" required>
<input formControlName="price" placeholder="prod quantity" required>
<input type="number" formControlName="value" value="{{calculateTotal()+ (calculateTotal() * 0.19)}}">
<input type="number" formControlName="vatValue" [value]="(calculateTotal() * 0.19)">
```

```
calculateTotal(): number {
    this.positions = this.invoicePositions.value;
    let tempValue = 0;
    for (const productValue of this.positions) {
      tempValue = tempValue + (productValue.quantity * productValue.product.price);
    }
    this.positions = [];
    this.invoiceTotal = tempValue;
    return tempValue;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.invoiceForm.controls.value.markAsDirty();
    this.invoiceForm.controls.value.markAsTouched();
    this.invoiceForm.controls.vatValue.markAsDirty();
    this.invoiceForm.controls.vatValue.markAsTouched();
    this.invoice = this.invoiceForm.value;
    console.log(this.invoice.value);
    this.invoiceService.save(this.invoice).subscribe(result => this.gotoInvoiceList());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Reactive Forms over Template-driven forms. In that case I'd recommend supplying the initial values to the form in your components `ngOnInit` rather than through the `[value]` attribute in the template.

In doing so, the values will be immediately available to you. You can then subscribe to change events to react to changes to any of values if necessary.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      price: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      value: new FormControl(
        this.calculateTotal() + this.calculateTotal() * 0.19,
        Validators.required
      ),
      vatValue: new FormControl(
        this.calculateTotal() * 0.19,
        Validators.required
      )
    });
  }
```

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uj174?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I'm reaching an error with this approach: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at InvoiceFormComponent.get invoicePositions [as invoicePositions] (invoice-form.component.ts:102) at FormComponent.calculateTotal" due to calculateTotal() function inserted in onInit() I think.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code to create the form?

Comment: I can share my github, but I'm affraid to share it here, how can I share the code with you in other way? Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your answer? The error is about "invoicePositions" not existing while we're building the "invoiceForm," so it'd be helpful to know what the difference between those two variables are.

Comment: Thanks, spots! I just solved this on backend side due to deadline of my projects, now I'm just displaying calculated value on front side, but in db is inserted that one from backend side.

Answer (score 0):

try [(ngModel)] instead of value of {{calculateTotal()+ (calculateTotal() * 0.19)}}